Debugging transaction Fails with `Status: Invalid`
I'm working with a function to send a transaction and wait for finalization using Polkadot.js. The function is intended to handle different statuses and errors, yet I randomly encounter "Invalid" transaction status without enough information to pinpoint the issue.
Here is my sendTxAndWaitForFinalization function:
// Generic function to send a transaction and wait for finalization
export async function sendTxAndWaitForFinalization(api, tx, signer) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        tx.signAndSend(signer, ({ status, dispatchError }) => {
            console.log("Transaction status:", status.type);

            if (dispatchError) {
                if (dispatchError.isModule) {
                    // Retrieve the error details
                    const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(dispatchError.asModule);
                    const { section, name, documentation } = decoded;

                    console.error(`Transaction failed with error: ${section}.${name}`);
                    console.error(`Error documentation: ${documentation.join(" ")}`);
                    reject(new Error(`${section}.${name}: ${documentation.join(" ")}`));
                } else {
                    // Handle other types of dispatch errors
                    console.error(`Transaction failed with error: ${dispatchError.toString()}`);
                    reject(new Error(dispatchError.toString()));
                }
                return;
            }

            if (status.isInBlock) {
                console.log("Included at block hash", status.asInBlock.toHex());
            } else if (status.isFinalized) {
                console.log("Finalized block hash", status.asFinalized.toHex());
                resolve(status.asFinalized.toHex());
            } else if (status.isDropped || status.isInvalid || status.isUsurped) {
                console.error("Transaction failed with status:", status.type);
                reject(new Error(`Transaction status indicates failure: ${status.type}`));
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error during transaction:", error);
            reject(error); // Reject the promise on error
        });
    });

When running this function, I receive the following output:
Transaction status: Ready
Transaction status: Invalid
Transaction failed with status: Invalid

How can I get more information on why this transaction is marked as "Invalid"?

It seems to happen when there's a reorg in the parachain.
